# Handle list of checkedboxes in the controller

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have the following code

```
<tbody>
                    @foreach (var item in Model.Select((value, i) => new {i, value}))
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.value.RfcacfAlphaNavigation.RfcrffNameFirst)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.value.RfcacfAlphaNavigation.RfcrffNameLast)
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.value.RfcacfAlphaNavigation.RfcrffTaxId)
                            </td>
                            @if (item.i == 0)
                            {
                                <td>
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.value.RfcacfAcct)
                                </td>
                                <td><div class="checkbox text-center"><label><input type="checkbox" /></label></div></td>
                            } else
                            {
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>

                            }
                        </tr>
                    }
```

I need to have a reference (in the controller) of the items that have been checked by the checkbox. How can I do this efficiently? 
(I have done some googling and for different reasons I can not bind this with the model, so I have to do it in a different way)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you've got three primary ways that data is going to be available in your controller.

- RouteData
- Request.Form
- Request.Query

Since you say you can't use model binding, which is just taking the data from one of those three places and mapping it into your view model for you, you'll need to pass the data in one of those ways from the client and retrieve it manually in the controller.

I'm assuming this code of yours is nestled in a `<form>`, being posted back to the controller.  In that case, using `Request.Form` is going to be a fairly straightforward way to achieve what you're trying to do.

1. On the client, create names for each check box which correlate uniquely to the items, using the item's id or name or somesuch.
2. In the `Controller`, when iterating over the items in the `ViewModel`, look for the value of the corresponding checkbox in the form using something like `Request.Form[itemId]`